# POST request is invalid

Tags: matlab, rest, request, http-post

I have a batch Post request to submit to an API through MATLAB. I do not know how to structure the body of my request in a valid way. Neither MATLAB nor the API's documentation offer any detailed enough help for me.

The request looks like this:

```
{
  "requests": [
{
  "id": "sample string 1",
  "seriesType": "sample string 2",
  "startDate": 1548882319358,
  "endDate": 1548882319358,
  "currency": "sample string 5",
  "sdkVersion": "sample string 6"
},
{
  "id": "sample string 1",
  "seriesType": "sample string 2",
  "startDate": 1548882319358,
  "endDate": 1548882319358,
  "currency": "sample string 5",
  "sdkVersion": "sample string 6"
},
{
  "id": "sample string 1",
  "seriesType": "sample string 2",
  "startDate": 1548882319358,
  "endDate": 1548882319358,
  "currency": "sample string 5",
  "sdkVersion": "sample string 6"
}
],
  "sdkVersion": "sample string 1"
 }
```

My current code looks like this:

```
M = length(entities);
K = length(series);
maxAttempt = 20;

method = matlab.net.http.RequestMethod.POST;
uri = strcat([api.baseURI 'Entities/SeriesBatch']);
body = matlab.net.http.MessageBody;
body.Data.requests = cell(M*K,1);
n = 0;
for ii = 1:M
    for jj = 1:K
        n = n + 1;
        body.Data.requests{n} = struct;
        body.Data.requests{n}.id = entities{ii};
        body.Data.requests{n}.seriesType = series{jj};
        body.Data.requests{n}.startDate = startDate;
        body.Data.requests{n}.endDate = endDate;

    end
end

N = 0;
response.Completed = true;

while and(response.Completed, N < maxAttempt)
    clear response
    header = myAPIHeader(api);
    request = matlab.net.http.RequestMessage(method,header,body);
    response = send(request,uri);
    N = N + 1;
end
```

However I get an invalid request message. This was my best guest on structuring this large batch request (M = 1133, K = 5).

Comment: How are we supposed to reproduce your problem (without so much as a link to the API)? Did you try sending the request through a dedicated tool (such as [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) or [API Tester](https://apitester.com/))? Are you sure that your request is even correct before trying to implement it in MATLAB? Do you have some way of capturing a correct request (e.g. using a browser's debug console or Wireshark)? Perhaps there are some missing headers like an API Key (or another way of authentication)?

Comment: The API is private and cannot be accessed by the public. I already have valid requests and response. I just cannot structure my data for a batch post request. More simple requests were return with positive response. No headers are missing.

Comment: To clarify, my problem is not with the API, but with MATLAB's language and body construction functions. 

Authentication has already been tested. Simple get requests where the data is passed in the URI are working fine. I cannot get a request with a multidimensional structure body to work. 
The sample request above is from the API documentation. There is no so much as a relevant code example in any of MATLAB's documentation.

Comment: Did you make sure that your `Data` struct is correctly converted to JSON ([`jsonencode`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/jsonencode.html))? Maybe it adds another layer of array/object wrapper that messes your request up...

Comment: When I do not use jsonencode, I get 'Bad Request' with the json response. If I do, I get 'Internal Server Error'. The API manager told me that my date should be formatted to UNIX epoch time in milliseconds, which was not the case right now. I'll be trying that with or without the jsonencode.

I'm able to obtain my data with a loop of GET requests without body (data in URI), but it takes 5+ hours to process about 5500 individual requests and the necessary outer join of output tables.